# In QEMU, is it possible to intercept packets being sent/received by the Linux Guest OS?

Tags: linux, sockets, virtualization, system-calls, qemu

We are doing a little project that involves monitoring the Guest OS (for example Linux) from the hypervisor layer (i.e. QEMU). One of the things that we want to monitor is network traffic going in/out of the Guest OS. Is it possible to do so without modifying the Guest OS?

One way to do it is to intercept the relevant syscalls which are made when sockets are created and fetch the values from the relevant registers as the instructions are being executed. But we are not too sure if it is easy or if its the right way to do it.

Answer (score 8):

In addition to @usr57368 answer -
For devices created with ’-netdev’, use ’-object filter-dump,...’ instead -net dump:

```
-object filter-dump,id=id,netdev=dev,file=filename][,maxlen=len]
```

> Dump the network traffic on netdev dev to the file specified by
>   filename. At most len bytes (64k by default) per packet are stored.
>   The file format is libpcap, so it can be analyzed with tools such as
>   tcpdump or Wireshark.

Answer (score 7):

From the [QEMU documentation](http://qemu.weilnetz.de/qemu-doc.html#sec_005finvocation):

> `-net dump[,vlan=`*n*`][,file=`*file*`][,len=`*len*`]`
>
> Dump network traffic on VLAN *n* to file *file* (`qemu-vlan0.pcap` by
>   default). At most *len* bytes (64k by
>   default) per packet are stored. The
>   file format is libpcap, so it can be
>   analyzed with tools such as tcpdump or
>   Wireshark.

You should also be able to monitor in real-time by running Wireshark on the host if you `--net tap`.

Answer (score 0):

use a program called wireshark.  Enter the search filter (ip.src eq [IP] or ip.dst eq [same ip])  and, it will tell you all the data going to and from that computer.  Useful for looking
deeper into it's interaction with the network, or certain actions.

Comment: However, if you use the default NAT networking, you won't be able to easily distinguish between traffic originating from the host and traffic originating from the VM in wireshark. So you'd need to use a different type of networking, as the other answer says.

Answer (score 0):

Since qemu is open source, you can get the source and insert code into the network device emulation to capture and log the data packets as they come through the device.  For example, see the virtio_net_flush_tx() routine in hw/virtio-net.c.

Comment: I think this answer is misleading not because it is wrong, but because QEMU already includes code to dump network traffic (as shown in other answers above) - while this answer is effectively, and unnecessarily, suggesting that users (re)write the same feature for themselves. And then because pretty clearly in almost all cases it will take much more time and effort - and be much less maintainable - to write a feature like this than to use an existing implementation, if there is one. (If this answer predates such support - I have not checked - then that is understandable!)